# Limit of Suprema of Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

This is my first post here.  I'm trying to play by the rules, so forgive me if it seems I'm asking too much.

I've been working on the following problem:

Let $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$, and $\ f_n:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}\ \ n\geq 1\ $, $\ f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be integrable functions such that $0 \leq f_n \to f$ a.e.,  and $\int_\Omega f_n d\mu \to \int_\Omega f d\mu$.  Show that 
$$
\lim_{a\to\infty}\sup_{n\geq1}\int_{\{f_n\geq a\}}f_nd\mu=0.
$$
Here's my initial attempt:

By Egorov's theorem, we may obtain, for all $n\geq N$, $|f_n-f|<\epsilon_0$ on the set $\Omega \backslash A$, with $\mu(A)<\delta$, i.e. for all $n\geq N$ we have $f-\epsilon_0\leq f_n \leq f+\epsilon_0$ on $\Omega\backslash A$.  Now, we may choose an $a_1$ such that

$$
\max_{1\leq n\leq N}\int_{\{f_n\geq a_1\}}f_nd\mu<\epsilon
$$

by the integrability of $f_n$.  Noting that for $n\geq N$ we have $\{f_n>a\}\subset\{f+\epsilon_0>a\}$, similarly (and this is somewhat awkward) we may choose an $a_2$ such that 
$$
\int_{\{f+\epsilon_0\geq a_2\}\backslash A}(f+\epsilon_0 )d\mu<\epsilon
$$
where the integrability of $\epsilon_0$ comes from the finiteness of $\mu(\Omega)$.  This gives for all $n\geq N$
$$
\int_{\{f_n\geq a_2\}\backslash A} f_n d\mu \leq \int_{\{f+\epsilon_0\geq a_2\}\backslash A}(f+\epsilon_0 )d\mu<\epsilon.
$$
Letting $a=\max\{a_1,a_2\}$, we have, for all $n$
$$
\int_{\{f_n\geq a\}}f_nd\mu = \int_{\{f_n\geq a\}\backslash A}f_nd\mu + \int_{\{f_n\geq a\}\cap A}f_nd\mu
$$
$$
<\epsilon +  \int_{\{f_n\geq a\}\cap A}f_nd\mu
$$
So this holds for suprema as well.

Now, I'm trying to make use of the fact that $\mu(A)<\delta$ for the remaining integral, but I'm not sure how to proceed.  I imagine this is where I need to make use of convergence of the integrals.  I'm sure, given the awkwardness of this attempt, there is a better approach as well. Thanks!

**Edit**

I found a way to deal with the remaining integral, as I posted below, but I'm still curious to see if there is a more elegant approach to this problem. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By no means you are asking too much, and +1 for showing your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the remaining piece can be dealt with.  Since the $f_n$ are all non-negative, we can show using Fatou's lemma that for all measurable $E\subset\Omega$
$$
\int_Ef_nd\mu\to\int_Efd\mu.
$$

Then by Vitali's convergence theorem, the sequence is uniformly integrable and hence we can choose a $\delta$ such that $\mu(A)<\delta$ guarantees that 
$$
\int_A f_nd\mu<\epsilon
$$
For all $n$. In particular,
$$
\int_{\{f_n>a\}\cap A} f_nd\mu<\epsilon
$$
The conclusion follows.